# how to use asp.mvc masterpage on non mvc page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc web site that contains one non-mvc page (it is using ajax and java-script, so mvc is not a good option).

The problem is that I still want to use the same masterpage. If I set the masterpage (MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"), then I get this error:

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".

Is there a way I can use my mvc masterpage for a non-mvc page?

Comment: it is using ajax and java-script, so mvc is not a good option, can you explain that one some more please.

Comment: I have been caught by the gotcha that: The IDs for controls are being renamed before being output in the HTML since the controls are inside a naming container, so when I try a $find for example the control does not exist because mvc has renamed it. 

When I have looked into using webform controls within mvc I have got comments along the lines "server-side WebForms controls are generally not supported inside an MVC ViewPage.  If you want to use MVC ViewPages, you'll have to find libraries that were written specifically for MVC. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading more about using controls within MVC, it seems the key thing is to use MVC compatible controls (rather than try to cobble together a combination of frameworks).

So in my case I should throw away the $1000 html editor software that was bought for this project, and use CKEditor or TinyMCE instead.

**Update:**
I have successfully implements TinyMCE in MVC, and it is working great

Answer (score 0):

It's strange you say "...not a good option..." as AJAX and Javascript are not reliant at all on the MVC framework. 
If you want to continue with this approach, turn off custom errors in the web.config to find out what is going on with this page and update your question.

Web.Config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have a separate master page for normal aspx pages since the reason mentiopned by Grayson.